# Combo box is changing the order of my number sequence in table

Tags: excel, ms-access, combobox

I am looking for some help please.

I have a combo box that is linked to a table which is a linked excel sheet saved on a network.

The table contains a column that has numbers in the form:

> -1
> -0.75
> -0.5
> 0
> 0.5
> 0.75
> 1

The above is how I want the list to show in the combo box, however it is changing to;

> 0.5
> 0.75
> 1
> 0
> -0.5
> -0.75
> -1

The column is formatted as numbers in the original excel spreadsheet and I have tried multiple customized options. I have also tried changing the "sort" option on the combo box.

Any ideas how I can get the combo box to show me my list in its natural form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in a database the records have no natural order. The order you see when opening a table is not guaranteed to remain the same. Instead of just specifying a table name as data source of the combo box, specify a SELECT query having an ORDER clause.

```sql
SELECT theColumn FROM theTable ORDER BY theColumn
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Not having any luck I am afraid.

Comment: I manually retyped my lengths in the spreadsheet as text and then changed the format to number and this somehow worked.